# Prove that $a.b = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 +a_3 b_3 $ where $a.b$ is inner product of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: calculus

if $a = (a_1, a_2,a_3 )$, $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3 )$, $c$ be three vectors.

prove that $a.b = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 +a_3 b_3 $ , where $a.b$ is inner product of $a$ and $b$.

definition of inner product: $a.b = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 +a_3 b_3 $

can you help me?

Comment: Isn't this just the definition of the inner product?

Comment: What is your definition?

Comment: Can you help me proving that $a@b=a^{b+a}$, given that the definition of $a@b$ is $a^{b+a}$? Also notice that the third vector, $c$, is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are given a definition logically earlier that the inner product $a \cdot b$ of two vectors $a := (a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}), b:=(b_{1},b_{2},b_{3})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is the real number $|a||b|\cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle made by $a$ and $b$.

Note that $(0,0,0), a,b$ form a triangle. Note that the square of the length of the side $\overline{ab}$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{3}(a_{k}-b_{k})^{2}$,
which by the Cosine theorem about a triangle is equal to
$|a|^{2} + |b|^{2} - 2|a||b|\cos \theta = \sum_{k=1}^{3}a_{k}^{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{3}b_{k}^{2} - 2a\cdot b.$